# Некорректно создается новая ветка

Tags: git

После нескольких ревертов, и ребэйзов turtoise git стал странно себя вести.
Имеется удаленная основная ветка, когда я создаю на ее основе свою *checkout -b*, то создается некорректная ветка.
Некорректная в том, что сразу после создания, push(в основную ветку) не пустой.
В нем присутствуют одни и те же левые комиты.
Единственный доступный пока выход: создавать ветку удаленно в *github* или *demolap* .

Comment: Первая идея: локальная ветка создается на основе remote tracking branch, которая не соответствует remote branch, потому что на remote был какой-то откат. Проверить можно пуллом этой ветки.

Comment: И что происходит, если из консоли создавать ветку?

Comment: сделал пулл, все в норме. После пуша чистой ветки, я попытался сделать compare ее и транка. Вот что появилось : *You'll need to use different branch names to get a valid comparison.*

Comment: хм. Сообщение такое, как будто один из предлагаемых объектов невалиден, нет его.

Comment: а репозиторий закрытый? Можно ли на него посмотреть как-то? Кстати, может заработать, если заново клонировать. Не встречался с таким, но ощущение, как будто перепутаны рефы в remote tracking branch где-то. Еще - для compare использованную команду можете процитировать?